# Trying to overdrive LEDs my power supply amperage mysteriously "backs off"

Tags: power-supply, led, led-driver, led-strip, led-matrix

I have a 48 parallel matrix of 3v LEDs. I'm trying to overdrive it. I set my supply to 3v and 0.5amps and the display glows. Up the amperage to say 1amp it gets brighter. So far so good. I keep increasing the amperage, and it gets more-or-less linearly brighter, UNTIL I reach some sort of threshold where I just can't drive it any harder. I was sort of expecting the LEDs to burn out, but instead my supply mysteriously backs off to what I'm assuming to be the max power (amps) that the LEDs can "pull" (?) -- let's call it 2 amps for this example. I can set the supply as high as I like, and all it does it to back itself off to 2 amps. There's no fancy electronics in the LED array, so presumably some sort of current limiter in the supply is doing this, but why, and how does it "know" where to land, rather than just burning out my LEDs like I was hoping it would do? (My supply is a very stable and reliable Hyelec HY50-06A.) Thanks in advance for any guidance you can offer.

Comment: What voltage do you have the supply set to?  If it is still set to 3V, try increasing it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LEDs are drawing whatever current they draw at the voltage you are supplying. If you want them to draw more current, you will need to raise the voltage.

Every simple two-terminal component has an I-V curve, which gives the current it will draw for a given voltage, or the voltage that will appear across it for a given current. Your "3V" LEDs are no different -- they need approximately 3V to function, but they still have an I-V curve, it's just a very steep one. At slightly less than 3V, they won't draw enough current to light up; at slightly more than 3V, they will draw enough current to destroy themselves and stop working.

Your power supply can't give both a fixed voltage and a fixed current to the circuit; for a given voltage the circuit will draw some specific current, or for a given current it will develop some specific voltage across it. So when you set both knobs, one or both are functioning as upper limits, not exact values. Your power supply is providing 3V to the circuit, and at that voltage the circuit draws some amount of current. It doesn't matter how high you set the current limit on the power supply; the circuit won't draw more than that.

If your circuit is truly just made of LEDs with no other components, it's really just luck that you happen to have found a voltage where they light up but don't explode. It's not recommended (and not practical) to drive LEDs with a constant voltage source, because even small manufacturing variations (or temperature changes) can cause large changes in current, for a given voltage.

If you are lighting up an array of parallel LEDs with a constant voltage supply, and they are all the same brightness, I suspect what's actually happening is that your array *does* contain other components, probably at least resistors, which are helping to regulate the current to the LEDs. You could give us more information about the LEDs and it might confirm this.

Comment: Thanks! This is clear and makes sense. There may well be embedded resistors. I’ll check and report.

Comment: I found a particularly clear page on this. http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/